# Binding from List with Objects

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

enter code hereMy Property from Object won't be shown on Datagrid.

I expect a string in column category, which is defined in the XAML of this project. The "Id" and the "Description" are successfully displayed on the DataGrid but the "Category" is not. See Screenshot below.

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="view" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="-4,0,4,0" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" Binding="{Binding Id}" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Category.Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Beschreibung}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        Start();
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        var payments = new List<Payment>();

        using (var dc = new DataContext())
        {
            payments = (from c in dc.Categories
                        join p in dc.Payments
                        on c.Id equals p.CategoryId
                        select p).ToList();
        }
        view.ItemsSource = payments;
    }
}
```

Here is My Payment Class

```
    public partial class Payment
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Beschreibung { get; set; }

    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public int IsIncome { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And here is My Category Class

```
    public partial class Category
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Category()
    {
        Payments = new HashSet<Payment>();
    }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

[image: string in column expected]

Comment: Can you share your DataContext, Categories and Payments class?

Comment: Show your Category and Payment class.

Comment: The 2 classes are shown now

Comment: Isn't it a bit recursive since you have list of payments inside of categories inside of payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this code

```
payments = (from c in dc.Categories
    join p in dc.Payments
    on c.Id equals p.CategoryId
    select p)
    .ToList();
```

to

```
payments = (from c in dc.Categories
    join p in dc.Payments
    on c.Id equals p.CategoryId
    select p)
    .Include("Category")
    .ToList();
```

It will eagerly load `Category` from database and it should fix your problem.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you Alexander, can you explain me whats the different between my and your selection? (I'm new with the entity framework)

Comment: @NikolaMatovic see this docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data.
Shortly, all properties marked as `virtual` are lazy loaded by default. It means that they are not filled with any data when you select them from database. But when you refer to the property in code the data is loaded. But it seems that WPF does something else than refering to propery when binds its value. So you just mannually tell EF to load this entity for you in single request.

Answer (score -2):

Is better to implements MVVM pattern, please take a look in:

[MVVM Code project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level)

So your bug is that in your linq you are selecting p (Payments) and maybe there the Category property is empty. You can do a quick watch to the query result and look it.

Comment: I debugged my programm and its curiose, sometime is the property category in the object payments null and sometimes it is not, without I changed something